# Minimizing trigonometric expression

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima

How can one get the minimum of a trigonometric expression if the first-order derivative is not in a nice form?

The expression is this:

$$
\left[\cos ^{2}\left(\dfrac{\theta }{2}\right) +
\,\sqrt{\,{1 - \gamma}\,}\,\sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{\theta }{2}\right)\right] ^{2} + \dfrac{\gamma }{4}\,\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)\quad
\mbox{where}\quad 0 \le \gamma \le 1.
$$
I have tried to solve this but I reach a term which is not easily solvable.

Comment: Try to substitute $\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})=t$

Comment: @tommycautero Hello, I was trying and you can see this nice answer from heropup...I am embarrassed to say still I can't make the complete solution. My minimum that I find looks scary....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $$\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1 + \cos \theta}{2}, \quad \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{2},$$ and $$\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta.$$ So if we let $x = \cos \theta$, we get the function $$\begin{align}f(x) &= \left( \frac{1 + x}{2} + \sqrt{1-\gamma} \frac{1 - x}{2} \right)^2 + \frac{\gamma}{4} (1 - x^2) \\
&= ax^2 + bx + c,
\end{align}$$ where $$\begin{align} a &= \frac{1 - \gamma - \sqrt{1-\gamma}}{2}, \\ b &= \frac{\gamma}{2}, \\ c &= \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-\gamma}}{2}. \end{align}$$  Now compute the critical point(s) of $f$ with respect to $x$ and consider where these have absolute value less than or equal to $1$, since we require $|x| = |\cos \theta| \le 1$.

Comment: I have upvoted it. I will work out now. Thank you.

Comment: I am surprised after this wonderful hint still I am getting stuck. For example, the critical point would be $-b/2a$ But then if I try to plug that value in $ax^{2}+bx+c$ then it doesn't give a nice solution. Also if I try to do $-b/2a$ having abs value less than 1, it leads to nowhere because a contains a quadratic term which I can never get rid of. Can you give me a hint regarding what minimum value did you find?

Comment: If your function is $h$, you need that $h(\theta)=f(\cos(\theta))$ and hence $h^{\prime}(\theta)=f^{\prime}(\cos(\theta))\cdot (-\sin(\theta))$ (chain rule). 

$h^{\prime}(\theta)$ is exatly zero if $\sin(\theta)$ is zero or if $f^{\prime}(\cos(\theta))$ is zero.

Comment: Yes here $f'(cos(\theta))$ is $2ax+b$ and have you checked if we analyze the way heropup has suggested we don't find any good expression.That's why I am confused @garondal.

Comment: Yes. $f^{\prime}(x)=0$ has no solutions since you get $x>1$. So the only critical points are at $\sin(\theta)=0$.

Comment: @garondal Well that is the question how do you get it is greater than 1? Because $x = -\gamma/(2*(1-\gamma -\sqrt(1-\gamma)))$

Comment: Correct. You have for $\gamma>0$:
$$x=\frac{\gamma}{2(\sqrt{1-\gamma}+\gamma-1)}> \frac{\gamma}{2(1-\frac{\gamma}{2}+\gamma-1)}=1.$$
 I used here $\sqrt{1-x}< 1-\frac{x}{2}$ iff $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @garondal: Thanks a lot.